# Seeking a "snap on" display for STM32

Tags: displays

I would love to use the STM32WB, but it doesn't have a display.

I am absolutely ***not*** a hardware guy. Does anyone now of a display for STM32 which just clips on? Soldering is beyond me :-)

I am open to OLED and also eInk.

A solution involving a snap-on shield which lets me use Arduino shields would also be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options:

- Chose a board with has Arduino Morph connectors like https://nl.mouser.com/new/stmicroelectronics/stm-p-nucleo-wb55/ 
  You can attach an Arduino shield (with display) on top of it? Check if there are drivers for it or examples.
- There are development boards with include STM32 and a display, I think some STM32 Discovery boards have them. Although according to https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-discovery-kits.html#products it seems none has STM32WB (with WB) and a TFT.
- You can also use a breadboard or jumper wires to connect the display to your STM32 (as long as your STM32 has male or header pin headers).

Comment: Are there any disco kits for the WB?

Comment: @JanDorniak It seems not, see https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-discovery-kits.html#products, there you can search for discovery kits, and with properties (including TFT).

Comment: Yeah, just saw that parametric search myself.

Comment: @JanDorniak too bad (thanks for the notification/question, I updated my answer to add this note).

Comment: Although the OP posted a very similar question and there is an F413 disco, with WiFi but no BT